# Cloud SQL External Access suddenly restricted

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have an Google Cloud Endpoint with an configured Cloud SQL - Database with an dedicated IPv4 for external access.
It all worked fine until today, where suddenly the access was restricted from EVERY IP I allowed.

Also "allow all" with 0.0.0.0/0 is not working any more.

I have checked the IP and it's all the same, server and client. 
Anyway its possible for my Endpoint to access it ( its locally there, so no ip check required).

Is there any way how to check if they currently have problems with it on their servers? I don't know what i can/should to in this case.
Thanks for your help in adanvance

Comment: did you try to reboot your Cloud SQL instance to see if it fix the issue?

Comment: I rebooted the instance several times. Also changing password was not possible. 

I created now another user, which worked. And THEN i was able to re-change the root password and then it worked -.- 
Must be a strange server issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding a new user, i was able to access the SQL instance again,... 
Then I changed the password several times and back to the old one. Obviously it's working again. But I don't know why it didn't work before.